# 2019 Acura TLX 4 Cyl FWD Vibration

Tags: vibration, shaking, motor-mounts, wheel-balance

I just bought a 2019 Acura TLX tech package, 4 Cyl CPO. Drives really well, but after a little while on the highway I can feel some vibration through the floor seats and steering wheel. I feel a small vibration when idling but that’s probably just due to it being a 4 cyl. Anyone have any suggestions? 38k miles on it, have an appointment in a week but would love some input.

Comment: I'd be looking at the wheels and tires, the axle shafts (i.e. CV joints), and if AWD the drive shaft.

Comment: It's a 2019 so you would think the axle shafts and u joints would be good, but the symptoms match and anything is possible. It could also be something faulty with the engine. A severe misfire would cause vibration, but it would also have a check engine light. So I would have to agree with jwh20.

Comment: You might think that but we know nothing of the history of this vehicle.  For all we know it was flooded and the CV joints have rotted from the inside out.

Comment: How do the CV joints rotate when idling?

Comment: The OP discounts vibration when idling.  But please feel free to offer your own theories.  Very little to go on here.